# PHP Facebook connect redirection to unauthorized URL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect

I've been working on facebook app to get api key from the user and use to get info such messages and notifications.

The problem I have is with facebook connect button:
in my facebook app I authorize an URL for the app but the project working on separated machine in LAN (with access to the WWW) so I made the connect at public domain: https://kerenproject.net/social.php and authorized this url at the app page.

The problem I have is how to "include" this social.php link at my project lan based website which is unauthorized?

For this moment I do some kind of redirection but it shows me the button "connect with facebook" every time, is there any way to redirect to social.php and get the api key back?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add in your local host file (/etc/hosts on mac i.e.) an entry like `127.0.0.1 mysite.local`.
Then you add mysite.local in the Facebook App and you are ready to use it on your local machine.

If you have a default apache installation or you use something like MAMPP, http://mysite.local will standard redirect to your webroot. It is also possible to create vhosts, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: I think you got me wrong .. I don't need to use at my local site .. each person has a local website in a device from my project, the device (192.168.1.X) needs to get api key for the user for facebook but facebook allow access only to authorited website to the application. so I can access the project domain which is kerenproject.net and from there the request goes to facebook, and then the domain gives back the details to the device, is that possible with iframe or something?

Comment: So you have 1 app but want to get this to work for multiple websites at different locations (doesn't matter if they are in a local network or not). You could write an own small API where the clients communicate with kerenproject.net and kerenproject 'forwards' that request to facebook en forwards the facebook response back to the client. No need for iFrame. Facebook doesn't support multiple domains for 1 app but does support subdomains: client1.kerenproject.net, client2.kerenproject.net and so on... Hope this helps you